# How to send email from GCP with C# and without using SMTP?

Tags: c#, google-cloud-platform, c#-4.0, firebase-cloud-messaging, nodemailer

I have been trying to look for different alternatives to send emails from `GCP` not using the `SMTP` protocol in a `C#` code.

I have a requirement to send an email from the `GCP Cloud Run` wherein I cannot use the `SMTP` protocol.

The only alternative that I could find that is not using the `SMTP` protocol is the `NodeMailer` module from `NodeJS`. But, I would need an equivalence for `C#`.

Comment: Instead of telling us the protocol that you *don't* want to use, can you edit your question to be clear about what you *do* want to use to deliver email?

Comment: You can send email using SMTP in your Cloud Run application. You cannot use port 25 however. Connect to a service like Gmail, Office 365, Zoho, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this [information](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/sending-mail) finds you well. As stated there, Google Cloud does not place any restrictions on traffic sent to external destination IP addresses using destination TCP ports **587** or **465** instead of port **25**.

Due to the risk of abuse, connections to destination TCP Port **25** are blocked when the destination is external to your VPC network, however you can use the ports already mentioned.

Additionally, if you have a support package, you could request the GCP support to **enable port 25** and this request would be reviewed for approval.